# How to construct an instance of Dictionary<string, List<string>>

Tags: c#, object-initializers

I am trying to code in C#, but I find that I can't construct an instance in this way like C++:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> FirSet =
    new Dictionary<string, List<string>>() {
        { "a", {"ab", "abc"} },
        { "b", {"bc", "bcd"} }
    };
```

Comment: You need `new List<string>()` before your list items.  So `{ "a", {"ab", "abc"} }` should become `{ "a", new List<string>() {"ab", "abc"} }`

Comment: Do you really need a `List<string>` or can it be a `string[]` array? You can use that initialization syntax with arrays. For lists, you need to new one up for each dictionary value.

Comment: @itsme86 wouldnt you still need to new up an array in that case? `new [] { "some", "example" }`?

Comment: You're also missing a closing `}`

Comment: @maccettura Oops, you're right.

Comment: I'd like to throw out another viewpoint: your structure might be getting convoluted enough that you might not want to one-line it.  If I was creating multiple entries in a nested structure like this, I'd break it out into a blank new Dictionary<...> line, followed by a myDict.Add(...) line for each element to add to the dictionary.  It's around the same level of readability (maybe a bit more readable) and it's a shade more maintainable (since you don't have to worry so much about all the various brackets.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var firSet =
        new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
        {
            { "a", new List<string>() {"ab", "abc"} },
            { "b", new List<string>() {"bc", "bcd"} }
        };
```

You can also use the C# 6.0 syntax:

```
    var firSet =
        new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
        {
            ["a"] = new List<string> {"ab", "abc"},
            ["b"] = new List<string> {"bc", "bcd"}
        };
```

And if you feel particularly lazy and you don't want to type all these `new List<string>` you can always do this:

```
    var firSet =
        new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
        {
            { "a", new[] {"ab", "abc"} },
            { "b", new[] {"bc", "bcd"} }
        }
        .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value.ToList());
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to initiate the lists within the dictionary with `new List<string>()`

Here how it should work:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> FirSet = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
    { "a", new List<string> { "ab", "abc" }},
    { "b", new List<string> { "bc", "bcd" }}
};
```

Comment: Minor point, but if you're going to drop the `()` (which I prefer) from the latter list creation, you should also do it for the first one.

Comment: Since our answers are (now) the same, I've deleted mine and upvoted yours.

Comment: @DavidG yes you are completaly right, its unnecessary, but since its possible i wanted to show both ways. might help FreAk Apoint in the future

Comment: @ZoharPeled thank you, to be fair i just threw the answer out, dmigo was so kind to format it like it is